# oracle transposing with analytical function

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, window-functions

I am transposing key value pairs from a table and facing an issue.
I am using `Oracle 12C database`.
Test data looks like this. table is `tab1`

```
 +---------------------------+
 | Name | VAL  |  ID | grp_id|
 +---------------------------+
 |   a  |   3  |  1  | 1     |
 |   b  |   5  |  2  | 1     |
 |   c  |   8  |  3  | 1     |
 |   c  |   9  |  4  | 2     |
 +---------------------------+
```

My expected result is

```
 +-------------------------+
 | grp_id|   a  |   b  | c |
 +-------------------------+
 |   1   |   3  |   5  | 8 | 
 |   2   | null | null | 9 |  
 +-------------------------+
```

What I did so far is

```
with t as(
select row_number() over (partition by grp_id order by grp_id) rn,
name,
grp_id,
lead(val,0) over (partition by grp_id order by grp_id) as a,
lead(val,1) over (partition by grp_id order by grp_id) as b,
lead(val,2) over (partition by grp_id order by grp_id) as c
from tab1 where grp_id  in (1,2) and name in ('a', 'b','c')
)
select grp_id,a,b,c from t where rn=1;
```

When data is consistent and for all `grp_id`-s key value pairs are the same then this query works fine, But in case when some keys are missing for one `grp_id` then I get a result like the following which is wrong and not what I expect

```
 +----------------------------+
 | grp_id|   a  |   b  | c    |
 +----------------------------+
 |   1   |   3  |   5  | 8    | 
 |   2   |   9  | null | null |  
 +----------------------------+
```

How can I improve the query to work correctly? And I want to avoid using `pivot`

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `pivot`? Also: are `a`, `b` and `c` the only names, or can there be others too? And if there can be others, are they known ahead of time, or only by looking at the data first? (And, why do you want to do this anyway - and especially, why in SQL? When this needs to be done, which is actually not often, it is usually done in the reporting layer, not in SQL.)

Comment: @mathguy I don't like ``pivot``. There can be more names. So when this issue is solved I'm going to dynamically get all the names, and with use of dynamic sql execute it. This needs to be done in SQL, it's just so.

Comment: Obviously it will not be done **in SQL** if you need to use dynamic SQL; that requires PL/SQL, which is quite different from (even though closely integrated with) SQL. It would also help to understand **why** you don't like `pivot`. It would be better if you would learn how to use it properly; it's not that hard, really. And God help you if you need to write the code for dynamic SQL using the "old style" of pivoting (as in Gordon's answer). It's bad enough to write it with `pivot`, and so much worse without it. Good luck all the same!

Comment: @mathguy for me with pivot  query gets unnecessarily complex. especially when there are lots of distinct keys. And yes I know the scopes of SQL and PL/SQL :) thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select grp_id,
       max(case when name = 'a' then val end) as a,
       max(case when name = 'b' then val end) as b,
       max(case when name = 'c' then val end) as c
from tab1
group by grp_id;
```

`grp_id` is already defined so I see no need for analytic functions.

Comment: First thought were analytics, and missed this way of transposing. Thank you. Before accepting this as an answer I'll wait maybe someone will suggest improvement with ``lead``. It's just still interesting if it is possible to get my expected result with analytical functions. It's challenging for me :)

Comment: @arminrock - there is no "improvement with lead"; pivoting has absolutely nothing to do with analytic functions. What Gordon has shown here is the way pivoting was done before Oracle introduced the `pivot` operator to make everyone's life easier. You may Google for "pivoting in Oracle 10" (even here on Stack Overflow there must be 100 threads about it) and you will convince yourself of this.

Comment: @mathguy Man take it easy this question is not a matter of life and death, coding is fun, don't limit yourself , maybe someone will suggest and maybe it will preform better than case and pivot :) And please remove duplicate the questions are from different perspectives. And yet so much activity from you on this post but no real suggestion or a code snippet or a proof that analytics won't work for transposing :)

Comment: @arminrock - The correct way to solve the problem is with PIVOT, or in earlier versions of Oracle, like Gordon has shown. Another very highly rated forum member (not me!) posted exactly the same answer as Gordon, then deleted it - exactly the right thing to do. If I were to post something it would be EXACTLY what Gordon posted, so why would I? Then - the question IS an exact duplicate; if someone finds a cool solution they should post their answer THERE, not here. Please familiarize yourself with the StackOverflow rules before you object.

Comment: @arminrock - by the way: the reason I did not upvote Gordon's answer (I didn't) is that I think his action was incorrect. He knows just as well as I do that this is a duplicate, and he should have done what I did: Close the question as a duplicate, not post the same answer the 100th time.